# How to use VBA to duplicate a sheet and then rename it (all in one sub)?

Tags: vba

I am able to rename the activesheet using the following code but need to combine this with (first) duplicating the original sheet:

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Dim strName As String
    strName = InputBox("Budget2")
    If strName = "" Then
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Name = strName
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Copy` without parameter will create a new workbook with the sheet copy, is that the intended result?

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you check if the new sheet name already exists.
- Make sure you keep track of where the copied sheet appears eg. after the source sheet `SourceSheet.Copy After:=SourceSheet` so you can pick up it's index which is 1 after the source sheet's: `Set NewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet.Index + 1)`.
- Finally make sure to catch errors on renaming if user entered not allowed characters or too long sheet names.

So you would end up with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopySheet()
    Dim InputName As String
    InputName = Application.InputBox("Budget2", Type:=2) '2 = text: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox#remarks
    
    ' user pressed cancel or entered nothing
    If (VarType(InputName) = vbBoolean And InputName = False) Or InputName = vbNullString Then
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' check if new sheet name already exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim TmpWs As Object
    Set TmpWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(InputName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not TmpWs Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The Sheet '" & InputName & "' already exists", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim SourceSheet As Object
    Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    
    SourceSheet.Copy After:=SourceSheet
    
    Dim NewSheet As Object
    Set NewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet.Index + 1)
    
    On Error GoTo ERR_RENAME
    NewSheet.Name = InputName
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Exit Sub
    
ERR_RENAME:
    MsgBox "Sheet could not be renamed.", vbCritical
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Copy) for the `Worksheet.Copy` method, using it *without* specifying either the `Before` or `After` argument will create a new Workbook, containing only that Worksheet.

So, to add a copy of the ActiveSheet after the ActiveSheet in the same Workbook, you can just change `ActiveSheet.Copy` to `ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet`